# Find an element by text, get xpath and put in a list as every td is a unique element - selenium webdriver junit

Tags: xpath, arraylist, getelementbyid

I have a dynamically generated table with thead and tbody. Here is the example:

```
<tbody id="tableId" class="someclass1">
<tr id="rowId1" class="somesubclass">
<td id="item1" class="othersubclass">
    <span class="attr">john Doe</span>
<td id="item2">
    <span class="attr">55</span>
<td id="item3">
    <span class="attr">5 street</span>
<td id="item2">
    <span class="attr">cat</span>
<tr id="rowId2" class="somesubclass2">
<td id="item1" class="othersubclass2">
    <span class="attr">joe smith</span>
<td id="item2">
    <span class="attr">60</span>
<td id="item3">
    <span class="attr">2 street</span>
<td id="item2">
    <span class="attr">dog</span>
```

|joe doe|55|5 street|cat|
|joe foo|60|1 street|dog|

I would like to locate a row by text where the name is joe doe and put it into a list.

Locatior is working with this, but it is not a list.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//tbody[contains(@id,'tableId')]/tr[td//text()[contains(.,'joe doe')]]")
private List<WebElement> list;
```

I got the list, but I cannot iterate over because everything has put into the first position like this:

list first element is: **joe doe 55 5 street cat** so this is the [0] element

How can I locate this row as a list where every td is a unique element in the list.

(iterate over, converting to string etc. is not a problem, just the locator.)

Thanks!

Comment: Which language are you using ? Java/PHP/Python ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it. Java + selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what's for the -1. Anyway, here is the answer for others, hope this helps!

There is a good plugin for google kinda firepath: SelAssist, I use it to test my xpath locators.

The problem was that, td was missing. So the proper locator is

```
//tbody[contains(@id,'tableId')]/tr[td//text()[contains(.,'joe doe')]]/td
```

and it gives me list of elements, not only one.

Cheers!